# Spring Security LDAP Server Connection Not '127.0.0.1'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I've a ldap server and i want to use spring security with this ldap. My connection configure is :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override 
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
    .userDnPatterns("OU=*****")
    .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")    
    .groupSearchBase("OU=*****")
    .contextSource()
    .root("DC=*****,DC=*****,DC=*****") 
    .port(389);




}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
}
```

}

But when i run my spring boot app, it tries to connect ldap://127.0.0.1:389, how can i access my ldap server? My ldap server url is : LDAP://xxx.com.tr

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

i did not see any configuration in your Spring security to specify the LDAP URL though.

try to use the url to specify the LDAP server, otherwise, it by default is using localhost...

```
  @Override
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
      .ldapAuthentication()
          .userDnPatterns("OU=*****")
          .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")    
          .groupSearchBase("OU=*****")
        .contextSource()
          .url("ldap://xxx.com.tr:389/dc=***,dc=***,dc=***");
  }
```